# How to create ImageView dynamically, positioning these using coordinates saved in a Graph?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, graph

I'm making an Android app for indoor navigation.

I have an ImageView that represent the floor map and one graph (made with JGraphT) that contain vertices and edges. I must position these vertices over the floor map like ImageViews with ball form.

The problem is that I have three floors in the structure and I want create and position the vertices depending on the floor selected and I don't know how can I do this.

I search more and more and more information about RecyclerView (but it seems that is used for List), DataBinding (I lost a lot of hours to try to work with databinding and I'm searching an alternative way).

Comment: This doesn't sound like an ImageView, it sounds like you need to make a fully custom view and draw the vertices where you want.

Comment: @GabeSechan YESS I think that this is the solution. Thank you!!!